# Jquery will not run at all

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I'm having issues with JQuery. I'm trying to learn it so I put this little web page together to test it out and everything looks correct, but I still can't get it to work on jsfiddle.net (which says it is valid code) or on my computer.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>I listen to music</title>
    <style>
        #box
        {
        height:50px;
        width:50px;
        background-color:black;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#box").on('click', function () {
                alert("hi");
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box">asdf</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the URL you are trying to load......

Comment: I think the code looks just fine. And it seems to work fine in jsfidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/QwrUs/ The url is right too, so I wouldn't know why this wouldn't work.

Comment: @asawyer Nothing is wrong with that url.

Comment: here is your fiddle working http://jsfiddle.net/YyApE/

Comment: The url i sfine, that is how you load jquery without caring about http vs https

Comment: @asawyer: Using `//` will make it use whichever protocol you are currently on `http` vs. `https`.

Comment: Well, learn something new every day then. Cool.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your jsfiddle where it appears to not work for you?

Comment: OP, can you confirm that you are viewing your webpage off your filesystem, and not through a web server? If your url starts with file://, you need to update your src attribute to jquery's CDN with the http:// prefix to indicate you don't want to use the file:// protocol

Comment: I got it to work thanks to @user1 but yeah I should have put the Http on there. I was working on jquery in a more complex of a situation but couldn't get it to work at all so I tried to make sure I had a grasp on how the syntax and such should have been working by making this post.

Comment: Awesome, everyone who gave the answer the OP needed got downvoted :)

Comment: if you are doing local dev work. download xampp or some local dev environment. it will give you a better understanding.

Comment: @ChrisHardie To be fair, none of the other downvoted ones (as far as I saw) besides you pointed out that `//` would incorrectly use `file:` for loading jQuery, so their answers were not complete/correct. It is unfortunate your answer was downvoted so much. I'm still not sure why `//` didn't work in jsfiddle for OP.

Comment: Optimus Prime was downvoted, but he got upvoted to come out positive. Was the jfiddle not working for you? I was using stewbydoo's jsfiddle, works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Works fine on jsFiddle.

**But if you are trying it on your system, you will need to provide src with `http` or `https`. It won't work with `//` off your file system, because then it will use the `file://` protocol, but in a jsFiddle it will use `http`.**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>I listen to music</title>
<style>
#box
{
height:50px;
width:50px;
background-color:black;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#box").on('click', function () {
    alert("hi");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box">asdf</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote. I have tested it and this works.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `//` (which OP uses) is a valid protocol placeholder on URLs. It simply means use the  same protocol as the parent page.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but why are you recommending changing CDN's? Google's CDN is fine. Also, that's a different version than the OP wanted.

Comment: I didn't notice your change from Google's CDN to jQuery's link. There have just been so many people insisting that the link is wrong due to the `//` that I had thought you were saying as much (since you're loading a similar version). Regardless, @Paulpro's point is valid in that the original link works just fine (I checked it myself, too, to make sure).

Comment: @Paulpro Oh..I tried that on my system. It didn't but on changing the src it did. However, this answer seems useless then, will delete it.

Comment: @OptimusPrime It won't work with `//` off your file system, because then it will use the `file://` protocol, but in a jsFiddle it will use `http`.

Comment: I have tried original but it does not work for me and it failed to load jQuery.

Comment: @Paulpro Hope this version of answer is something useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if your working locally:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: There is nothing wrong with the URL. Look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Here is your Fiddle:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YyApE/)

Comment: @Optimus Prime seems to have it ^^

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me very well. Link:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').on('click',function(){
alert('Hi');    
    })

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/63nrR/

Comment: You're correct, and this is helpful, but it should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to work fine for me:
[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/W953s/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#box").on('click', function () {
     alert("hi"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried to change the "alert" to 
     $(this).animate({
  left:100,
  top:100
 });

Comment: but that didn't work. Sorry for the two comments for one post.

Comment: @JarrenSeanBrown Is that the part that didn't work? If so, you need to set the css of your div to `position:relative` or `position:absolute` so the `left` and `top` properties have an affect.

Comment: I am not really profiecient on css but http://jsfiddle.net/ttdfK/ seem to work for me

Comment: Oh! That made it work! Thank you. I'm just picking Jquery up, so I miss little things like that. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

Change your reference to jquery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*EDIT*

Ok, before I get more downvotes here, // is a vlaid protocol. But since the OP is likely testing from his file system (protocol file://), // will result in jquery not being pulled in.

If the OP changes the src to use http://,  jquery will download regardless of the protocol to view the page.

Comment: The comments in the question have already stated that OP's use of `//` for the protocol is perfectly valid (it means use the protocol of the parent page), so adding `http[s]:` should be unnecessary.

Comment: I know that it would use the `file:` protocol if the browser is directly loading the file from the filesystem (that's why I said that it uses the protocol of the parent page, as `file:` is a valid protocol), but this still doesn't explain why it doesn't work in his fiddle (which, granted, is not yet provided for us to look at).

Comment: I copied and pasted his code into a webpage I put on my machine. After updating the protocol, it works entirely as expected. Here, for extra credit, on my own server, the original code unaltered: http://www.nextdesigns.ca/foo/foo.html

Comment: It works as it should, the solution the OP was after is to declare the http:// protocol, which was my answer.

Comment: @ChrisHardie He said it's not working in a jsFiddle. A jsFiddle is already using `http`, so this doesn't solve his problem.

Comment: I can't speak to his jsfiddle, but I can speak to his code working flawlessly once I uploaded it to my server. As he indicates in the comments of his question, he simply needed to alter the protocol calling the jquery CDN to specify http.